# Bridge PSTN calls using Freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch

(Note: FS-> Freeswitch)
Following is the use case that I want to achieve using FS:

1. FS makes an outbound call to a PSTN user A.
2. A picks up the call and is greeted with a welcome message.
3. A then dials another PSTN number (that of user B) using the dial pad.
4. FS captures the number and calls B.
5. B picks up the call and FS joins A and B.So that A and B can communicate with each other now.

Answer (score 1):

it's quite easy. You build an IVR which accepts the destination number and bridges the call to B. Then you call the `originate` command from CLI or external script to call A and execute the IVR.

You probably need to read the [FreeSWITCH](http://www.packtpub.com/freeswitch-1-2/book) book first :)

Comment: Can you link to the FreeSWITCH book? Thanks.

Comment: It's on the front page of freeswitch.org , the bridge book

Comment: Oh wait there's no bridge on this edition. The freeswitch 1.2 book